# PHTML to PHP for PDF print out purpose

Tags: pdf, list.phtml, index.php

I have some difficulties to convert some phtml codes into php (note: simple conversion with online tools html to php does not work therefore please do not answer if it is to refer online tool).
Below is the phtml code that I would like to add in .php file:

```
<?php 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
                ->load($_item->getProductId());
?> 

<div style="float:left;width:100px;padding-right:10px;">
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')
                         ->init($_product, 'image')
                         ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                         ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                         ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                         ->resize(100,100); ?>" 
alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />             
</div>
```

When I converted to php I added those lines as below the code is not working:

```
         $order  = $this->getOrder();
            $item   = $this->getItem();
            $pdf    = $this->getPdf();
            $page   = $this->getPage();
            $lines  = array();
    echo "<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())->load($_item->getProductId()); ?>";

            // draw Product name
            $lines[0] = array(array(
   echo "<div style=\"float:left;width:100px;padding-right:10px;\"><img src=\"<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(100,100); ?>\" alt=\"<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>\" /></div>";
                'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($item->getName(), 50, true, true),
                'feed' => 35,
            ));
```

Therefore can you tell me what should I modify to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign all the html code into a variable and concatinate with respective php variables.

```
<?php
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
    ->load($_item->getProductId());

$imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')
            ->init($_product, 'image')
            ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
            ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
            ->keepFrame(FALSE)
            ->resize(100,100);

$outputData = '<div style="float:left;width:100px;padding-right:10px;">
    <img src="'.$imageUrl.'" alt="'.$_item->getName().'"</div>';

echo $outputData;
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but within a .php file isn't strange to put <?php ....?> ?

Comment: No. Without php start and end tags, code will not be compiled.